# How to resolve runtime error 3075 in access query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function using allen Browne's method of concatenate

http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

The code works, and it works well within my query.

However, when I try to left join the Concatenate query against my union query, I get `20` or so popups stating an error, and then the query opens up showing the info...very strange. At moment, I've worked around it by using a `Dlookup` on my continuous form.

I've tried amending the syntax between integer and string, but same error occured.

I've tried combining the concat function into one query, then joining that query, same issue.

Query I want to join to main query.

```sql
SELECT 
   tblCUSTOMERREF.aglgrnID, 
   tblCUSTOMERREF.CustomerRef, 
   ConcatRelated("CustomerRef", "tblCUSTOMERREF", "[aglgrnID] = " & [aglgrnID]) AS 
   CustomerRefs
FROM 
   tblCUSTOMERREF;
```

Main query - Just pulling info from everywhere...

```
SELECT 
   AGLGRNextended.*, 
   ([tblPRODUCT].[productSUPPLIERSKU]&" - "&[tblPRODUCT].[productDESCRIPTION])AS Description, 
   tblPRODUCT.[productSUPPLIERNAME], tblAGLGRN.[aglgrnCREATED], 
   tblSCANIN.[scaninUSER], tblSCANIN.[scaninUSERTIME], tblUser.[UserName], 
   tblUser.[UserFIRSTNAME], Val(AGLGRNextended.[PROD]) AS PROD1, 
   Format(tblAGLGRN.aglgrnDATEEXPECTED,'Short Date') AS DateExpected,  
   tblAGLGRN.aglgrnUSER AS AGLGRNUSER,
   tblUser.UserFIRSTNAME AS AGLGRNFIRSTNAMEUSER
FROM 
   (((((AGLGRNextended LEFT JOIN tblPRODUCT ON [tblPRODUCT].[productGS1SKU]=[AGLGRNextended].[GS1SKU]) 
   LEFT JOIN tblAGLGRN ON [AGLGRNextended].[AGLGRN]=Format(tblAGLGRN.AGLGRN,'00000')) 
      LEFT JOIN tblSCANIN ON [tblSCANIN].[ID]=[AGLGRNextended].[SCANINID]) 
         LEFT JOIN tblUser ON [tblUser].[UserLogin]=[tblAGLGRN].[aglgrnUSER])) 
            LEFT JOIN CustomerRefqry ON Format([CustomerRefqry].[aglgrnID],'00000') = Format(tblAGLGRN.AGLGRN,'00000')


UNION SELECT 
   Null AS Field2, 
   tblCOMPANYDIRECTORY.companyCODE AS Field3,  
   Format(tblAGLGRN.AGLGRN,'00000') AS AGLGRN,  
   Null AS Field4, Null AS Field5,  
   Null AS Field6, Null AS Field7,  
   tblAGLGRN.aglgrnCUSTOMERREF, 
   tblAGLGRN.aglgrnSUPPLIERREF, 
   tblAGLGRN.companyID,  
   Null AS Field9,  
   PackageCountqry.PackageQty AS Packages,  
   Null AS Field10,  
   Null AS Field11, Null AS Field12,  
   Null AS Field13, Null AS Field14,  
   Null AS Field15, Null AS Field16,  
   Null AS Field17, Null AS Field18,  
   tblAGLGRN.aglgrnSUPPLIER AS Field19,  
   tblAGLGRN.aglgrnCREATED AS Field20,  
   Null AS Field21,  
   Null AS Field22,  
   Null AS Field23,  
   Null AS Field24,  
   Null AS Field25,  
   tblAGLGRN.aglgrnDATEEXPECTED AS DateExpected,  
   tblAGLGRN.aglgrnUSER AS Field26,  
   tblUser.UserFIRSTNAME AS AGLGRNFIRSTNAMEUSER
FROM  
   (((((tblAGLGRN LEFT JOIN GS1DECODEextended ON Format(tblAGLGRN.AGLGRN,'00000') = Format(GS1DECODEextended.[AGL GRN],'00000'))  
    LEFT JOIN tblPACKAGES ON Format(tblAGLGRN.AGLGRN,'00000') = Format(tblPACKAGES.aglgrnID,'00000'))  
    LEFT JOIN PackageCountqry ON Format(tblAGLGRN.AGLGRN,'00000') = Format(PackageCountqry.AGLGRNPACKAGE,'00000'))  
    LEFT JOIN tblUser ON tblUser.UserLogin = tblAGLGRN.aglgrnUSER) 
    LEFT JOIN tblCOMPANYDIRECTORY ON tblAGLGRN.companyID = tblCOMPANYDIRECTORY.ID)  
   LEFT JOIN CustomerRefqry ON Format([CustomerRefqry].[aglgrnID],'00000') = Format(tblAGLGRN.AGLGRN,'00000')
WHERE  
   Format(tblAGLGRN.AGLGRN,'00000') <> Format(GS1DECODEextended.[AGL GRN],'00000')
ORDER BY  
   AGLGRNextended.[AGLGRN] DESC;
```

`[aglgrnID] =` comes up as the syntax problem. The `tblCUSTOMERREF` doesn't give me this, its only when I left join it to the table.

So I don't know what I am missing...

Comment: Can't tell, but you may obtain better results using my [DJoin](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.DJoin) function.

Comment: Do not use `*` in queries with `UNION`. You have to make sure the resulting fields are exactly the same in number, name, type and sequence for every subquery of the `UNION` and using `*` makes that very difficult.

Comment: Can you show how/where you are doing the join?

Comment: Cannot replicate issue with my data. LEFT JOIN works.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the *, I'll try that and see if it stops the error, and come back with the renewed query code.

Comment: Right, it seems the * was the issue in the union query!! :) I have no popups now after typing in all the fields manually. Thank you SunKnight0!

Comment: I'll take a look at your function Gustav.